# Get varcov matrix LMM with random intercept and continuous first order autoregressive correlation structure with heteregenous variances?

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models, nlme, autoregressive-models

I have repeated measurements data on 66 patients with either endogenous or exogenous depression (`endo`) and depression scores measured weekly for 0-5 weeks (`hdrs` and `week`, so six measurements per patients including baseline). The data is in a long format:

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(nlme)

mydata <- structure(list(id = c(101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 103, 103, 
103, 103, 103, 103, 104, 104, 104, 104, 104, 104, 105, 105, 105, 
105, 105, 105, 106, 106, 106, 106, 106, 107, 107, 107, 107, 107, 
108, 108, 108, 108, 108, 108, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 114, 114, 
114, 114, 114, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 
117, 118, 118, 118, 118, 118, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 121, 
121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 302, 302, 
302, 302, 302, 302, 303, 303, 303, 303, 303, 303, 304, 304, 304, 
304, 304, 305, 305, 305, 305, 305, 305, 308, 308, 308, 308, 308, 
308, 309, 309, 309, 309, 309, 309, 310, 310, 310, 310, 310, 311, 
311, 311, 311, 311, 312, 312, 312, 312, 312, 313, 313, 313, 313, 
313, 313, 315, 315, 315, 315, 315, 316, 316, 316, 316, 316, 316, 
318, 318, 318, 318, 318, 318, 319, 319, 319, 319, 319, 319, 322, 
322, 322, 322, 322, 327, 327, 327, 327, 327, 327, 328, 328, 328, 
328, 328, 328, 331, 331, 331, 331, 331, 331, 333, 333, 333, 333, 
333, 333, 334, 334, 334, 334, 334, 335, 335, 335, 335, 335, 335, 
337, 337, 337, 337, 337, 337, 338, 338, 338, 338, 338, 338, 339, 
339, 339, 339, 339, 344, 344, 344, 344, 344, 345, 345, 345, 345, 
345, 345, 346, 346, 346, 346, 346, 346, 347, 347, 347, 347, 347, 
348, 348, 348, 348, 348, 348, 349, 349, 349, 349, 349, 349, 350, 
350, 350, 350, 350, 350, 351, 351, 351, 351, 351, 351, 352, 352, 
352, 352, 352, 352, 353, 353, 353, 353, 353, 353, 354, 354, 354, 
354, 354, 355, 355, 355, 355, 355, 355, 357, 357, 357, 357, 357, 
357, 360, 360, 360, 360, 360, 360, 361, 361, 361, 361, 361, 361, 
501, 501, 501, 501, 501, 501, 502, 502, 502, 502, 502, 502, 504, 
504, 504, 504, 504, 504, 505, 505, 505, 505, 505, 505, 507, 507, 
507, 507, 507, 507, 603, 603, 603, 603, 603, 603, 604, 604, 604, 
604, 604, 606, 606, 606, 606, 606, 606, 607, 607, 607, 607, 607, 
607, 608, 608, 608, 608, 608, 608, 609, 609, 609, 609, 609, 610, 
610, 610, 610), week = structure(c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 
1, 2, 3, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 0, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 2, 3, 4, 
5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 
4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 
2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 2, 3, 5), format.spss = "F1.0", display_width = 6L), 
    week_fact = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
    6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
    6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 
    1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
    5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
    6L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
    5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
    6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
    6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
    5L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 6L), .Label = c("Week 0", "Week 1", "Week 2", 
    "Week 3", "Week 4", "Week 5"), class = "factor"), endo = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Exogenous", 
    "Endogenous"), class = "factor"), hdrs = c(26, 22, 18, 7, 
    4, 3, 33, 24, 15, 24, 15, 13, 29, 22, 18, 13, 19, 0, 22, 
    12, 16, 16, 13, 9, 21, 25, 23, 18, 20, 21, 21, 16, 19, 6, 
    21, 22, 11, 9, 9, 7, 21, 23, 19, 23, 23, 17, 11, 13, 7, 7, 
    16, 16, 16, 16, 11, 19, 16, 13, 12, 7, 6, 26, 18, 18, 14, 
    11, 20, 19, 17, 18, 16, 17, 20, 22, 19, 19, 12, 14, 15, 15, 
    15, 13, 5, 5, 18, 22, 16, 8, 9, 12, 21, 21, 13, 14, 10, 5, 
    21, 27, 29, 12, 24, 19, 17, 15, 11, 5, 1, 22, 21, 18, 17, 
    12, 11, 22, 22, 16, 19, 20, 11, 24, 19, 11, 7, 6, 20, 16, 
    21, 17, 15, 17, 18, 17, 17, 6, 21, 19, 10, 11, 11, 8, 27, 
    21, 17, 13, 5, 32, 26, 23, 26, 23, 24, 17, 18, 19, 21, 17, 
    11, 24, 18, 10, 14, 13, 12, 28, 21, 25, 32, 34, 17, 18, 15, 
    8, 19, 17, 22, 24, 28, 26, 28, 29, 19, 21, 18, 16, 14, 10, 
    23, 20, 21, 20, 24, 14, 31, 25, 7, 8, 11, 21, 21, 18, 15, 
    12, 10, 27, 22, 23, 21, 12, 13, 22, 20, 22, 23, 19, 18, 27, 
    14, 12, 11, 12, 21, 12, 13, 13, 18, 29, 27, 27, 22, 22, 23, 
    25, 24, 19, 23, 14, 21, 18, 15, 14, 10, 8, 24, 21, 12, 13, 
    12, 5, 17, 19, 15, 12, 9, 13, 22, 25, 12, 16, 10, 16, 30, 
    27, 23, 20, 12, 11, 21, 19, 18, 15, 18, 19, 27, 21, 24, 22, 
    16, 11, 28, 27, 27, 26, 23, 22, 26, 20, 13, 10, 7, 27, 22, 
    24, 25, 19, 19, 21, 28, 27, 29, 28, 33, 30, 22, 11, 8, 7, 
    19, 29, 30, 26, 22, 19, 24, 21, 22, 13, 11, 2, 1, 19, 17, 
    15, 16, 12, 12, 21, 11, 18, 0, 0, 4, 27, 26, 26, 25, 24, 
    19, 28, 22, 18, 20, 11, 13, 27, 27, 13, 5, 7, 19, 33, 12, 
    12, 3, 1, 30, 39, 30, 27, 20, 4, 24, 19, 14, 12, 3, 4, 25, 
    22, 14, 15, 2, 34, 33, 23, 11)), row.names = c(NA, -375L), class = "data.frame")

head(mydata)
   id week week_fact      endo hdrs
1 101    0    Week 0 Exogenous   26
2 101    1    Week 1 Exogenous   22
3 101    2    Week 2 Exogenous   18
4 101    3    Week 3 Exogenous    7
5 101    4    Week 4 Exogenous    4
6 101    5    Week 5 Exogenous    3
```

To examine if the pattern of change of depression (`hdrs`) is different between groups I've run two models. The first includes a random intercept and slope for time. The second model includes a random intercept for time (no random slope) and assumes a *continuous first order autoregressive correlation structure with heterogeneous variances for the residuals*:

```
model_ris <- 
  lme(fixed=hdrs ~ endo*week, 
      random=~1 + week|id, 
      method="ML", 
      data=mydata)


model_ri_car1_hetvar <- 
  gls(hdrs ~ endo*week, 
      correlation=corCAR1(form=~1|id),
      weight=varIdent(form=~1|week),
      method="ML", 
      data=mydata)
```

I've got two questions:

1. Have I specified the second model correctly? I've borrowed code from two different models (the `correlation=corCAR1(form=~1|id)` part is from someone useing `gls` to specify a cCAR(1) model, and the `weight=varIdent(form=~1|week)` is from code from `lme` originally in a AR(1) with heterogenous variances model) but I'm very much not sure if this is how I specify what I'm trying to do.
2. Is there a way to get a variance covariance matrix for the second model? I've tried `getVarCov` but that does not work. Calling `corMatrix(model_ri_car1_hetvar)` gives a correlation matrix, but I want a variance-covariance matrix.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: mabye check crossvalidation portal with same question!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/549805/get-varcov-matrix-lmm-with-random-intercept-and-continuous-first-order-autoregre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you've switched from an `lme` model to a `gls` model. Your description says "[t]he second model includes a random intercept for time", but (a) I'm not even sure what that means (did you mean to say "a random intercept across patients (`id`)" ?) and (b) `gls` models *don't implement random effects* (they're intended for when you want to model correlation and heteroscedasticity and *don't* want to include random effects in the model). I would say if you want a random intercept (across patients), a continuous-time autocorrelation structure (within patients), and different variances by week, you should use

```r
model_ri_car1_hetvar <-
 update(model_ris,
      random = ~1 |id,
      correlation=corCAR1(form=~1|id),
      weight=varIdent(form=~1|week))
```

(updating model only with the components that have changed).

In order to get a covariance matrix, I would say you should: (1) select the correlation matrix for some individual who was measured in every week;

```r
cs <- model_ri_car1_hetvar$modelStruct$corStruct
cormat <- corMatrix(cs)[["101"]] ## this individual happens be measured every week
```

(2) get the standard deviations for each week:

```r
hs <- model_ri_car1_hetvar$modelStruct$varStruct
## ?varIdent: "the coefficients of the variance function represent 
## the ratios between the variances and a reference variance 
## (corresponding to a reference group level).
sdvec <- sigma(model_ri_car1_hetvar)*c(1, sqrt(coef(hs, unconstrained = FALSE)))
```

(3) compute the covariance matrix:

```r
diag(sdvec) %*% cormat %*% diag(sdvec)
```

It wouldn't hurt to double-check everything/try this on some simulated data!

From your CV question:

> How much parameters for the correlation structure of residuals does the second model actually estimate? I know that AR(1) and cAR(1) models just estimate phi(or rho), but now that I've combined these correlation structures with heterogeneous variances, I'm not sure if my model is estimating a rho/phi for every timepoint for every patient (which wouldn't be a very good option). Could I see/check this anywhere?

One `phi` value. When you run `summary()` you can see the parameter estimates (`Phi: 0.5808927`). Alternately, `coef(cs, unconstrained = FALSE)` gives you that value.

---

When I add a random slope term to the model:

```r
model_ris_car1_hetvar <-
  update(model_ri_car1_hetvar,
      random = ~1 + week |id)
```

it actually works (R-devel, Linux): the "singular convergence" stuff tends to be very platform- and version-specific.  I would try `control = lmeControl(opt = "optim")` and see if it helps ...

Comparing the models, it seems that the random slopes are worth keeping but the correlations and heteroscedasticity might not be (depending on your modeling goal).

```r
bbmle::AICtab(model_ris, model_ri_car1_hetvar, model_ris_car1_hetvar)
                      dAIC df
model_ris              0.0 8 
model_ris_car1_hetvar  0.5 14
model_ri_car1_hetvar  11.4 12
```

Comment: Hi @Ben Bolker, thanks so much for the elaborate answer. 
- As for calling the `gls`, I indeed now see that that does not make sense (because I do have to incorporate random effects). by a random slope for time I indeed meant to say that I want to specify a random slope per patient (over time) in my model.
Step three (to compute a var-cov matrix) is very new to me, I will definitely try this method, thanks for the clarifications.

As a last question; model you named `model_ri_car1_hetvar`  with also random slopes. When I try to run this model, however, I get a convergence error.

Comment: Sorry I cant edit my comment anymore (took too long):

Comment: Hi @Ben Bolker, thanks so much for the elaborate answer. 
- By a random slope for time I indeed meant specifying random slopes per patient (over time).
- I did not know that about `gls`. I'll switch to/keep using `lme`.  
- Step three (to compute a var-cov matrix) is very new to me, I will definitely try this method, thanks for the clarification on this.

- As a last question; I'm trying to add a random slope to `model_ri_car1_hetvar`  but get a convergence error:  nlminb problem, convergence error code = 1
  message = singular convergence (7) Any Idea why?

Comment: I've asked this last question also on Cross Validated (someone thought it would be more appropriate over there): https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/549811/convergence-problem-running-linear-mixed-model-with-car1-correlation-structure

Comment: Sorry for the crossposts, I thought the convergence questino would be better asked seperately. I've deleted all other posts (they were unanswered).

Comment: Looking at the AICs  the random intercepts and slopes model is the best fit (and is the most parsimonious). My research question is etiologic, I want to assess if and how  much risk factors are related to change in my outcome over time. When would you say adding the correlation structure would be a good idea?

Comment: That's kind of a deeper question (how do I decide what model to use in this situation?) and would be better for CrossValidated ...